# Registering simple types in a specific example

Tags: dryioc

Consider the following

`ClassA` has a constructor that takes an instance of `MasterClass` and a `string` and exposes a property called `Names` of type `string[]`.

`ClassB` has a constructor that takes an `IJuicePresser` and a `IEnumerable<string>`.

`ClassC` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Manually I would do something like this to tie them together.

```
var masterClass = new MasterClass();
var juicePresser = JuicePresser.Create("default");
var classA = new ClassA(masterClass, "string");
var names = classA.Names;
var classB = new ClassB(juicePresser, names as IEnumerable<string>);
var classC = new ClassC(Array.Reverse(names));
```

How can I set up DryIoc to handle these registrations/resolutions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to move all these run-time names from constructors to corresponding methods. But here is the matching DryIoc setup as-is:

[Live on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QvRksR)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DryIoc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new Container();

        c.Register<MasterClass>();

        c.Register<JuicePresser>(Made.Of(() => JuicePresser.Create("default")));

        // an example how to inject a primitive value: "string" in this case 
        c.Register<ClassA>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<string>(_ => "string"));

        // service key is optional, just to distinguish the list of strings for consumer.
        c.Register<string[]>(
            Made.Of(_ => ServiceInfo.Of<ClassA>(), factory => factory.Names),
            serviceKey: "names"); 

        // register reverse names using ReverseHelper method
        c.Register<string[]>(
            Made.Of(() => ReverseHelper(Arg.Of<string[]>("names"))),
            serviceKey: "reverse-names"); 

        // specify the names and required type (string[]) for injection
        c.Register<ClassB>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<IEnumerable<string>>(typeof(string[]), serviceKey: "names"));

        // specify reverse names for injection
        c.Register<ClassC>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<string[]>(serviceKey: "reverse-names"));

        var classB = c.Resolve<ClassB>();
        var classC = c.Resolve<ClassC>();


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", classB.Names.ToArray()));
        // outputs: a - string - z

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", classC.Names));
        // outputs: z - string - a
    }

    public static T[] ReverseHelper<T>(T[] target) {
        Array.Reverse(target);
        return target;
    }

    public class MasterClass {}

    public class JuicePresser 
    {
        public readonly string Name;

        private JuicePresser(string name) { Name = name; }

        public static JuicePresser Create(string name) 
        {
            return new JuicePresser(name);
        }
    }

    public class ClassA 
    {
        public readonly string[] Names;

        public ClassA(MasterClass master, string name) {
            Names = new[] { "a", name, "z" }; // for example
        }
    }

    public class ClassB 
    {
        public readonly JuicePresser Presser;   
        public readonly IEnumerable<string> Names;

        public ClassB(JuicePresser presser, IEnumerable<string> names) {
            Presser = presser;
            Names = names;
        }
    }

    public class ClassC
    {

        public readonly string[] Names;

        public ClassC(string[] names) {
            Names = names;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

Explaining a bit the part with:

```
c.Register<string[]>(
    Made.Of(_ => ServiceInfo.Of<ClassA>(), factory => factory.Names),
    serviceKey: "names");
```

DryIoc has support for using not only constructors for service creation, but also static and **instance** methods (factory methods), properties and fields. Here is the [wiki topic](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/SelectConstructorOrFactoryMethod#markdown-header-factory-method-instead-of-constructor).

In example above we use `Names` property of `ClassA` object as *factory method* to register service type "string[]" with service key "names".

Let's see in detail:

```
// Registering service of ClassA. It means that it can be resolved / injected directly,
// or/and we can use it as a factory for resolving further services
c.Register<ClassA>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<string>(_ => "string"));

// Registering service of type "string[]"
c.Register<string[]>(
    // Made.Of enables specifying factory method to use for "string[]" resolution, instead default constructor selection rules.
    Made.Of(
        // 1) Specifying what factory object should be used,
        // Here we say to use ClassA service registered in container 
        requestNotUsedHere => ServiceInfo.Of<ClassA>(), 

        // 2) Specify that Names property of resolved ClassA object
        // should be used for "string[]" resolution
        classA => classA.Names),

    // As the "string[]" is not very distinctive (unique) service type 
    // (you might register other "string[]" with different meaning), 
    // we identify the names with "names" service key. So when injected or
    // resolved, you need to specify the service key in addition to type.
    serviceKey: "names");
```

If you want to register with static factory method, property, field, then you don't need to specify `request => ServiceInfo.Of<TFactory>()` part. BTW, `request` parameter can be used for conditional selection of factory.

Comment: Thanks! I think I follow what's going on. In the `ServiceInfo` line, does the registration apply `ClassA.Name` to all resolved `"names"`, or only if there is some dependence or reference to `ClassA`?

Comment: Added the Update section explaining Made.Of.

Comment: Cheers. Awesome support.