# DryIoc registering default primitives

Tags: dryioc

I have a boostrapper for the Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework where I just auto register all ViewModels in the assembly.

Some ViewModels have constructors with parameters, and I usually overwrite these manually (using the `Register`-parameter `ifAlreadyRegistered: IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace`) after my auto-registration is complete.

However, when a ViewModel has a primitive type, DryIoc automatically fills the type with a default value.

When I then manually register the ViewModel with the correct parameter, I get two registrations for the same ViewModel, where Caliburn.Micro will chose the default-filled one.

What is the proposed method of dealing with this stuff?

**UPDATE:**

---

`ctor ViewModel(DependencyA depA, string[] list)`

```
AssemblySource.Instance.SelectMany(Portable.GetAssemblyTypes)
.Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
.ForEach(type => _container.Register(type));
```

This get registered as `ServiceKey=DefaultKey.Of(0) registered as factory`

So I now know what list should be (after the auto-registration), and I register ViewModel again, this time with a different service-key which is linked to the actual `string[]`.

```
Container.Register<ViewModel>(
    made: Parameters.Of.Type<IEnumerable<string>>(typeof(string[])),
    serviceKey: "list");
```

This results in another registration `with ServiceKey="list" registered as factory`. I would like this named registration to replace the default, but I have to keep the name to actually populate the list.

The reason: Caliburn.Micro will attempt to resolve by type, and I would explicitly have to use Caliburns `IoC.Get<>()` to provide the key which would mean that I could not inject the `ViewModel` in the constructor.

Comment: Can you explain this bit better in a code "However, when a ViewModel has a primitive type, DryIoc automatically fills the type with a default value."

And how is this looks like "When I then manually register the ViewModel with the correct parameter"

Comment: I have attempted to do so in the update.

Comment: "but I have to keep the name to actually populate the list" you may other means to identify the service: required service type for instance.

Comment: How would that work? The actual details of retrieving `"list"` is in another discussion we had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916939/registering-simple-types-in-a-specific-example

Comment: Ah, ok. Ignore my last comment then. will think a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first attempt, you can try to solve the problem head on: via using container-wide factory selector rule `SelectKeyedOverDefaultFactory`:

```
var c = new Container(Rules.Default
    .WithFactorySelector(SelectKeyedOverDefaultFactory("preferable key")));

c.Register<I, A>();
c.Register<I, B>(serviceKey: "preferable key");
c.Resolve<I>(); // will resolve I of B

c.Register<X>();
c.Resolve<X>(); // will work as before (w/out rule) by falling back to default factory.
```

**But** I plan [another way](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/issues/195/composable-metadata-as-a-idictionary) of solving such cases in *the next* version.

Comment: This works, but it feels like a bit of a hack, because the container is polluted by specifics. Can I set multiple select keys?

Comment: Nope you cannot. The problem always has two ways of solving. String[] does not  align well with DI in general. May be you can wrap it in a service.

Comment: Can the default registration be overridden to resolve the one using the key?

Comment: It can be Unregistered.

Comment: I have tried that, but I need a way to resolve so `c.Resolve<ViewModel>` resolves to `c.Resolve<ViewModel>("key")`. This would be great.

Comment: You can use RegisterMapping<ViewModel, ViewModel>(registeredServiceKey: "key") exactly for that. If it works for your case, I will update the answer.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about RegisterMapping. The documentation states that it "Does nothing if registration is already exists.", and in my case the registration already exists (by the auto registration).

Comment: It means if registration with the same type and key is exist, it does nothing. In your case we are registering mapping with default (null) key for some non-default key.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference with the RegisterMapping. `c.GetServiceRegistrations` yields two registrations 1) `Ns.ViewModel with ServiceKey=DefaultKey.Of(0) registered as factory` 2) `Ns.ViewModel with ServiceKey="key" registered as factory` which doesn't change when I add the RegisterMapping.

Comment: I am answering on your comment: "I have tried that, but I need a way to resolve so `c.Resolve<ViewModel>` resolves to `c.Resolve<ViewModel>("key")`. This would be great."      Given the original context, Step 1: register batch from assembly source. Step 2: replace the specific registration with the one you need with IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace. Step 3: map new registration to the key.

Comment: The specific registration (step 2) is the one with "key", so how will it replace the one without any key?

Comment: I propose to replace it without key first (step 2), and then map the key to new default registration (step 3)

Comment: That didn't work. In RegisterMapping, it appears the it will IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep, so when I attempt to register map onto itself, will it not keep the already registered (non-keyed) type?

Comment: Not late at all. What I am trying to do is this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxbvEm where I would expect the Count() to display 3 if the mapping was successful.

Comment: Nice. Wrong URL though?

Comment: remove the serviceKey,  and replace regServiceKey with serviceKey